# Arithmetic problems known to be in TC^{i+1} but not known to be in TC^i

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

Is there an arithmetic problem that is known to be in $TC^{i+1}$ but not known in $TC^i$ for any $i\geq0$? Concrete examples for $i=0$ would be of most utility however any arithmetic example is fine.